# simple_form doesn't display right input despite attribute types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

If [I read right](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type), if I have an attribute of type `:date` or `:text`, `simple_form` is supposed to respectively display **by default** a `date select` and `textarea` input.

Which is not the case as far as I know.

Here is the concerned migration, which is the last:

```
class CompleteGroupActionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :group_actions, :concerned_object,  :string, null: false, default: ""
    add_column :group_actions, :concerned_company, :string, null: false, default: ""
    add_column :group_actions, :date,              :date,   null: false
    add_column :group_actions, :amount_estimation, :string, null: false, default: ""
    add_column :group_actions, :description,       :text,   null: false, default: ""
    add_column :group_actions, :tags,              :string
  end
end
```

The code for the form:

```
section
  .row
    h1= t('actions.new')

  .row
    = simple_form_for :group_action, url: admin_actions_path do |f|
      = f.input :concerned_object
      = f.input :concerned_company
      = f.input :date
      = f.input :amount_estimation
      = f.input :description
      = f.input :tags

      = f.button :submit
```

The HTML generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Nouvelle action</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/actions" class=
            "simple_form group_action" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div style="display:none">
                    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name=
                    "authenticity_token" type="hidden" value=
                    "d24b3skP/N3Dr94Udvny2Hzi9fZkWfHhEYArm09R8wo=">
                </div>

                <div class=
                "input string required group_action_concerned_object">
                    <label class="string required control-label" for=
                    "group_action_concerned_object"><abbr title=
                    "required">*</abbr> Produit ou Service
                    concerné</label><input class="string required" id=
                    "group_action_concerned_object" name=
                    "group_action[concerned_object]" style=
                    "background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                    type="text">
                </div>

                <div class=
                "input string required group_action_concerned_company">
                    <label class="string required control-label" for=
                    "group_action_concerned_company"><abbr title=
                    "required">*</abbr> Société concernée</label><input class=
                    "string required" id="group_action_concerned_company" name=
                    "group_action[concerned_company]" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="input string required group_action_date">
                    <label class="string required control-label" for=
                    "group_action_date"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Date
                    des faits</label><input class="string required" id=
                    "group_action_date" name="group_action[date]" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class=
                "input string required group_action_amount_estimation">
                    <label class="string required control-label" for=
                    "group_action_amount_estimation"><abbr title=
                    "required">*</abbr> Estimation du montant du
                    préjudice</label><input class="string required" id=
                    "group_action_amount_estimation" name=
                    "group_action[amount_estimation]" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="input string required group_action_description">
                    <label class="string required control-label" for=
                    "group_action_description"><abbr title="required">*</abbr>
                    Description du problème</label><input class=
                    "string required" id="group_action_description" name=
                    "group_action[description]" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="input string required group_action_tags">
                    <label class="string required control-label" for=
                    "group_action_tags"><abbr title="required">*</abbr>
                    Mots-clés / Tags</label><input class="string required" id=
                    "group_action_tags" name="group_action[tags]" type="text">
                </div><input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value=
                "Submit Group action">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no error when running my migrations. I don't want to hard set the type of input, otherwise I lose some benefits using `simple_form`.

```
$ bundle show simple_form
/Users/Adrien/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/gems/simple_form-3.0.2

$ bundle show rails
/Users/Adrien/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/gems/rails-4.1.6
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an object to simple_form_for helper, instead of a symbol.

```
= simple_form_for @group_action, url: admin_actions_path do |f|
```

Comment: Even if it's a form to _create_ a new object in my DB?